# Add item in order to a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

What is the best way to add an item to an ordered list?

I want that when an item changes the value the value of that control is placed on a list.

Example

-radiobutton value = radiobuttonvalue;
-checkbox value = checkboxvalue;
-textbox value = textboxvalue;

clicks: first on the checkbox than radiobutton and last textbox.

output:

```
<ul>
<li>radiobuttonvalue</li>
<li>checkboxvalue</li>
<li>textboxvalue</li>
</ul>
```

so i that it doen't matter in wich control is clicked first, the output is always in the same order.

Comment: can you post actual html? what you have there is a bit confusing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to output the values of your fields in the order of the fields in the form? If so, this might be what you're looking for:

```
$(function() {
  var fieldValues = [];

  $('.field').change(function() {
     // get the index of the field
     var fieldIndex = $(this).index();

     // store the value of the field in the array using it's index
     fieldValues[fieldIndex] = $(this).val();

     // our output list
     var $list = $("#output");

     // clear the list
     $list.html("");

     // loop through our values and add them to the list
     for(value in fieldValues) {
        $list.append("<li>"+fieldValues[value]+"</li>");        
     }
  });
});
```

html:

```
<input class="field" />
<input class="field" />
<input class="field" />
<input class="field" />

<ul id="output"></ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery:

```
$('input').change(function(){
    var value = this.value;
    $('#output').prepend($('<p>', {text:value}));
})
```

HTML:

```
<input type='...'/>
<input type='...'/>
<input type='...'/>
<input type='...'/>
<div id='output'></div>
```

---

Updated fiddle to use a list.

Here is the new js code:

```
$('input').change(function(){
    var value = this.value;
    $('#output').append($('<li>', {text:value}));
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/Ee7gY/